# Tablas Relacionadas en PHP para mostrar datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, web, tablas

Actualmente tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar, se debe que ocupo montar un grupo de 3 tablas en PHP que serelacionan en jerarquía, es decir, lo que muestra la segunda depende de la primera y lo que muestra la tercera depende la segunda.

Básicamente es algo parecido a este Excel que les muestro...

El tema que creo que es más complicado es que ocupo poder agregar tantas filas ocupe para cada tabla.

La aplicación la estoy haciendo en PHP con mySQL, pero estoy abierto a cualquier recomendación que me den ustedes

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask] pues del modo que publicas tu pregunta es muy amplia y se basa en opiniones motivos por los cuales terminará cerrada

Answer (score 0):

Entonces serían 3 consultas SQL...

La primera para obtener los que serían las categorías,

La segunda para obtener las subcategorías basadas en la categoría que se le pasa de la primera

La tercera para obtener el contenido en base al 1º y el 2º...

Sería así mas o menos:

```
$sql = "select * from categorias";
...

while ( $row = fetch ) {

    echo 'categoria';

    $sql2 = "select * from sub_categorias where categoria_id = $row['categoria_id']";
    ...

    while ( $row2 = fetch ) {

        echo 'sub categoria';

        $sql3 = "select * from productos where categoria_id = $row['categoria_id'] AND sub_categoria_id = $row2['sub_categoria_id'] ";
        ...

        while ( $row3 = fetch ) {
            echo 'contenido';
        }
    }
}
```